# How can I perform aggregate function logic across multiple fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate-functions, sql-server-2014-express

**How can I get max() of three dimensions to come from the same record?**

Description:
I have a large list of widgets, with multiple attributes, from multiple sources. Think manual data entry, where you have the same stuff being entered by different people, and then you need to consolidate differences. Though, instead of auditing each difference, I just want to perform some logic to choose a value over another under certain criteria.

An analogous example: if one source a says widget xyz weighs 3 pounds, and source b says it weighs 4 pounds, I am just blindly taking the 4, as it is greater, and say I need to be over cautious for packing/shipping purposes. That is easy, I choose MAX().

Now, I have a group of attributes that are in separate fields but related. Think dimensions of a box. There are width/length/height fields. If one source says the 'dimensions' are 2x3x4, and another says they are 3x3x4, I need to take the larger, for the same reason as above. Also sounds like MAX(), except...

My sources disagree on which is the width, height, or length. A 2x3x4 box could be entered 4x3x2, or 2x4x3, depending on how the source was looking at it. If I took the MAX of 3 such sources, I would end up with 4x4x4, even though all 3 sources measured it correctly. This is undesirable.

How do I take the greatest 'measurement' value, but make sure all three values comes from the same record?

If 'greatest' is impossible, we could settle for unique... except there is a fourth source, which has 0x0x0 for about 40% of the widgets. I can't leave a 0x0x0 if any of the other sources did in fact measure that widget.

some sample data

```
ID,widget_name,height,width,leng
(a1,widget3,2,3,4)
(b1,widget3,2,4,3)
(c1,widget3,4,3,2)
(d1,widget3,0,0,0)
```

output should be `(widget3,4,3,2)`

Comment: It is not at all clear what your question is here. Given your rather vague sample data what should be the output and why?

Comment: @SeanLange  Just finished adding the output as you commented. ...Why? Because my client is paying me to do so! :)

Comment: I mean the business rules. What should be the output and how do you come up with that? You said the output of 4x4x4 is undesirable but you didn't explain why that is wrong or what would be correct.

Comment: Still unclear - how is this data *stored*? Hopefully *not* as strings that you're expecting us to also *parse* before doing any work? If the data is properly normalized, then it should be straightforward to *sort* the various dimensional lengths before comparing them.

Comment: I could consider a 4x3x2 to be the greatest measurement value, even though it is equivalent to 2x3x4, and both are acceptable. On the other hand, if I had a 5th sample row, of (e1,widget3,3,2.5,4), I would need the dimension output to be 3x2.5x4

Comment: Yes you said that would be the output but you still have not explained why. What makes 4x3x2 > 2x4x3??

Comment: One problem is - when multiple dimensions are involved, there's no *total order*. If one input is 1x9x1 and the other input is 3x3x3 - which is the "max"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Great. Happy to hear this is all straightforward. For this example, assume that the 3 'dimension' fields are data_type float, and then I will apply it to varchar, etc. when necessary.

Comment: Thank you, these are reasonable questions. Let's say for my float data, we will sum(w+l+h) to find the max... so, 1x9x1 > 3x3x3, and 4x3x2=2x4x3, and I will let sort order/randomness/whatever decide the equivalent ones.

Comment: So, having decided that you can simply add together the height, width and length values to determine the "value" to be compared - is there still a question here?

Comment: Use some combined value, for example Volume or Length + Girth

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you for asking. The question is "
How can I get max() of three dimensions to come from the same record?"

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thank you, my concern is how to parse them once I concatenate, if I do that. If that is easiest (to concatenate into one field, and then parse out into 3 fields), I am not sure how to do that

Comment: It is better to have 3 separate columns. Else you will have to split string. Volume is self-evident. For Length+Girth you probably need a UDF which takes 3 args, sort them desc and produce `2 * (1st + 2nd) + 3rd`.

Comment: @AlexKudryashev Thank you, I misunderstood at first. You are saying to alter the table first, add a field that is a function of the 3 other fields I am working with, and then take the max() (or whatever function) of that field. That makes sense too.

Comment: @SeanLange, @ Damien_The_Unbeliever, Now that you see what I was looking for, how could I have improved this question so that it would have made sense to more people, including you, and not just Alex and Kostya? I am a PM, not a DBA, and I want to make sure that my communication is better than just adequate for the audience I am addressing.

Comment: The best would be to include a table with some sample data and an explanation of the business rules needed to determine the results. In this case was simple arithmetic of L*W*H but for me at least I was not clear what the rule was for "largest". In this particular situation you could also do a top 1 with an order by. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could use row_number instead of group by like

```
select * from 
(select data, ID,widget_name,height,width,leng, ROW_NUMBER() over ( partition by widget_name order by height + width + leng desc ) rowid
from yourTable
) as t
where rowid = 1
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I had no idea I could order by summed values. Do you know if this works in varchar too, or just numeric? I can always convert strings to numeric, measure length of string, or do something else, if I need to, but I would like the collation to do it for me, if possible.

Comment: Nevermind, I would need to work with strings differently anyway, since it would only order by the first character of the string, and not look at the whole string. I will look at using functions on string values in order by statements for my next step, but that is outside of the scope of this question. You answered what I needed, thank you.